# How to properly provide Authentication object (SecurityContext) to application itself?

Tags: spring, spring-security

Most of my application is secured with method level security (AspectJ, but it doesn't matter) and now that I am trying to call some code from within application itself (not controllers, but e.g. EventListener) I can't help to wonder if Spring Security provides some out-of-box way of giving Authentication object to the application itself, otherwise I cannot get past my method security since application has null security objects (Authentication in SecurityContext, if it even exists - depends on situation, You might have to init it first).

Sure I can do something like this (just before running relevant code):

```
UserDetails ud = User.builder()
                .username("APPLICATION")
                .password("APPLICATION")
                .roles("APPLICATION")
                .build();
        Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(ud, ud.getPassword(), ud.getAuthorities());
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                .setAuthentication(auth);
```

- But is it safe to do this in deployment (security-wise)?
- Is there any guarantee on which thread will own this SecurityContext? What about other threads and their tasks?
- Once set, can it stay there? Will it for the rest of app's run (can be days/months), context could be reloaded, etc. I lack deep Spring knowledge to know what happens Thread-wise inside Spring.

Comment: What do you mean by "application has null security objects"?

Comment: @NatFar Well, there is no SecurityContext (and Authentication) if You don't set it. Normally for example for http clients this is done in http filters when client connects through controller. Here I want to authenticate not a http client, but application itself. Difference is that when client connects - there is separate Thread with SecurityContext (and Authentication) for his session. For Application there is none (null) unless You set it. My question is - does Spring provide some better hooks for it, or do I literally do it like I did above?